# GDAL minidriver and Tilecache

Tags: gdal, tilecache, tile-map-service

I'm trying to use [GDAL minidriver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html) to read tiles folders generated from Tilecache seeding.

I have set this in my GDAL source `<ServerUrl>http://myserver.com/test/${z}/${x}/${y}</ServerUrl>`, and when I try to use gdal_translate with this minidriver file I have 404 error:

```
0ERROR 1: GDALWMS: Unable to download block 0, 0.
URL: http://myserver.com/test/8/0/0
HTTP status code: 404, error: (null).
```

The error is right because I have another kind of structure. In example I have `http://myserver.com/test/08/000/000/.`

It seems to me that the output of tilecache seeding process does not have a standard TMS structure, and for this reason I have these kind of errors. Am I wrong?

My source `SRS is EPSG:3004`. Could it be this the reason of a non standard TMS folders structure?

Comment: Are you sure you can access http://myserver.com/test/08/000/000/ files? TileCache uses padding for the Disk cache, but it should manage the padding even if you pass the unpadded integers...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question due to lack of feedback